# How to take Objecta nd Multipart file in same function in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-restcontroller

I am trying to create a controller function that takes Post requests to the /user. When testing on Postman I get `org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content-Type 'multipart/form-data;`. The function takes 2 objects, one I created and a MultiPartFile object, what Should I do?

UserService Controller, Post Function

```
    @PostMapping("/user")
    public ResponseEntity<?> save(@RequestBody UserSignUpDto user, @RequestParam("inpFile") MultipartFile file, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        System.out.println("Hi there 1");

        System.out.println(user.getEmail());
        System.out.println(user.getUsername());

        if (userService.doesUserExist(user)) {
            throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Username already exists.");
        }

        userService.setUserProfilePicture(user, file);
        User savedUser = userService.addUser(user);

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(savedUser);
    }
```

Postman:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should annotate both variables with `@RequestPart` annotation. For example:

```
@PostMapping("/user")
public ResponseEntity<?> save(@RequestPart UserSignUpDto user, @RequestPart("inpFile") MultipartFile file, BindingResult bindingResult) {
   System.out.println("Hi there 1");

   System.out.println(user.getEmail());
   System.out.println(user.getUsername());

   if (userService.doesUserExist(user)) {
      throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Username already exists.");
   }

   userService.setUserProfilePicture(user, file);
   User savedUser = userService.addUser(user);

   return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(savedUser);
}
```

I don't know what is BindingResult so i didn't touch it. You can look at the third section in [here](https://www.baeldung.com/sprint-boot-multipart-requests) for a short information.